# How to use the array of strings and display it line by line

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I display what has been added to my list and show it in the textbox line by line? I am adding data from a text file into a list so that I can append text after every line.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\File1.txt"))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    list.Add(line);
                }

            }

            TextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred" + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: You are right John. I edited to show what I tried thus far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
aTextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());
```

This will take every string in your array and add a newline between them.

Comment: Be sure to set your text box to multiline.

Comment: I don't know if `Environment.NewLine` depends on some current `System settings` but looks like its value is `\r\n`. BTW, since `.NET 4.0`, we don't need to pass in `an array` as the second argument, just an `IEnumerable<string>` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to show file source inside a `TextBox` there is no need to save the data inside a `List<string>` first. Just do:

```
string text = "";
using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\File1.txt"))
{
     string line;
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
          text += line + Environment.NewLine;
     }
}
aTextbox.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way - without looping through all the lines in the file.

```
using System.IO;

private void WriteFileContentsToTextBox(string filePath)
{
     // Always check for existence of the file
     if (File.Exists(filePath))
     {
        // Open the file to read from. 
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
        myMultilineTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.Newline, readText);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I want to loop because I need to set a condition and the result of that condition determines that I need to append some text to the end of each line. Hope that makes sense.